# clickonce signing is grayed out. UWP c# app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, clickonce, uwp

Its a helper app for in-house use.  I want to do a clickonce deployment as I usually do using vs2010/windows form.

Trying out UWP using vs2015.  After much pain I am ready to deploy the test version of the app and when I go to the projects/properties/signing the 'Sign the ClickOnce Manifests its grayed out.

I've been searching for a few evenings now but haven't come across anything to enlighten me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike WinForms applications that can be distributed via ClickOnce or other technologies like MSI, you distribute UWP applications through the Windows Store or via side-loading using (eg) a Powershell script. ClickOnce doesn't work for UWP.

[This Ignite presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3306) should help explain it, and the latest Windows Update should enable side-loading by default (so no need to enable it on each user's machine). You can also read more [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446593(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Thank got me going in the right direction.